# Ask before executing 'reboot'?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, reboot

I frequently (all day every day) have a minicom terminal tab open and execute commands on an embedded Linux system from my Ubuntu laptop.  Sometimes I have to execute the `reboot` command, and sometimes, I am ashamed to admit, I accidentally execute `reboot` in the wrong tab and my laptop does exactly what it was designed to do without asking any questions...

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and tried installing molly-guard but that has had no effect.

99 times out of 100 I don't mess up but my laptop takes a good 10 minutes to reboot and I execute `reboot` frequently enough for this to be an annoyance.

Is there some bit of black magic, I can add to my custom terminal window setup bash script, that will make `reboot` map to something else (just for that bash session preferably)?

Comment: How about white magic, such as the incantation of _not_ sitting at a superuser-privileged prompt so frequently an errant `reboot` will hose your workstation.

Comment: Maybe next time I reinstall my OS...  Right now all my paths are pretty much reliant on me being root and I am too lazy to fix them.  Also there is the horror of having to type 5 extra characters for every other command...  Nah defiantly better to spend my time making obscure workarounds and hacks to keep from messing up. :-)

Comment: That `molly-guard` isn't working is interesting, since it also implements a safeguard in a similar fashion to other solutions (/usr/sbin/reboot to take over /sbin/reboot). You mention a custom window setup function, does that muck with PATH already?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Won't necessarily fix things. If you're running a `systemd` using Linux (which Ubuntu 16.04 is) users who are the only ones logged into the system can restart the machine *without* elevating privileges (i.e. without `sudo`/`su`/logging in as root). I believe there's settings to control this behavior, but many of the single-user-oriented distros (like Ubuntu) turn it on by default.

Comment: @robbat2 Nope. 
 Here is my path (it matches the one in ~/.bashrc): 
 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the `~/.bashrc` file on your laptop (**not** on the embedded machine), add the line:

```
reboot() { echo  "Hey, don't do that!"; }
```

If you actually wanted to run `reboot` on the laptop, you can get around this function by running `sudo reboot` or `/sbin/reboot`.

---

Or, you could make it more friendly, as [man0v](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/122541/man0v) suggested, by using:

```
reboot () { echo 'Reboot? (y/n)' && read x && [[ "$x" == "y" ]] && /sbin/reboot; }
```

I suggest putting such a function in `~/.bashrc` because we want it available in interactive bash sessions.

##### Alternative

One may also want to consider the package `molly-guard` which is designed to protect machines from accidental shutdowns or reboots.  It is available on [debian](https://packages.debian.org/sid/admin/molly-guard) and can be installed via:

```
apt-get install molly-guard
```

Comment: or you could have `reboot () { echo 'Reboot? (y/n)' && read x &&  [[ "$x" == "y" ]] && /sbin/reboot }`

Comment: That is probably a better solution than the one I came up with, since mine involves modifying $PATH.

Comment: There is a debian package for that: `apt install molly-guard`

Comment: @Phlogi Excellent.  I added that to the answer.

Answer (score -2):

Okay, after playing around a bit more I found an okay solution:

I created a bash file named 'reboot' in /usr/sbin/ and then added the complete path /usr/sbin/reboot to the front of $PATH.

Here is the script:

```
read -p "Are you sure? " -n 1 -r
echo    
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    /sbin/reboot
fi
```

Maybe not the best solution though...

Comment: Very good.  One potential issue is that changing the system file `/usr/sbin/reboot` may cause problems with system utilities as well as X11/GUI programs that depend on the default behavior of `/usr/sbin/reboot`.

Comment: It also is still letting you keep your nasty habit of leaving superuser prompts open for errant `reboot` commands.

Comment: Actually I found I did not even have to type sudo for the reboot command to work, not sure why.  Not like I don't leave super user terminals open all the time anyway.  I mostly remember to lock my computer before walking away...  mostly. :-)

Comment: @John1024 no system utilities depend on `/usr/sbin/reboot`, since there's no such file in a stock system. The stock `reboot` binary is in `/sbin`.

Comment: -1 because: you shall not edit stuff in /usr/sbin

Comment: @Kamil there is an accepted answer and this post is 9 months old...